# Why is: margin-left: calc(height / -2); not working?

Tags: css

Tho I am trying to center a picture with height: auto;. I thoght "margin-left: calc(height / -2);"  is working... but it isn´t xD. Do u guys have an idea who this could work?

Comment: Center it vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Also, look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

The property calc dont accepts names for example 'height', and your second value is wrong, on your example to work you must use this:

> margin-left:calc(100% - 20px);

Lets try 100%, and then the operation you want to the browser make to you and then finally the second number.

For more informations of the property in the css called calc if you like to read the documentation here this a link: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Hope this helps.